# Text color formating Razor View Engine C#

Tags: c#, razorengine

I am learning C# and have a requirement for the problem I am working on. The task states:

> If the string in the array begins with the letter x, style the `<p>` element with red text.

How might I go about doing this?
I understand how to set it up

```
       <div>
            <p>@word</p>
            @if(word.Length <4) <!--anything under 4 char will be known as a short word.-->
            {
            <p>@word is a short word</p>
            }
            @elseif(word <!--beginning with c should be red-->) <!-- I don't know if "elseif" is usable or appropriate here-->
            {
            <p>@word <!-- but you know, in red--></p>
            }
      </div>
```

I apologize if this has been asked, I searched and did not find anything myself.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're after some CSS advice here. Styling is done with CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color. You can style inline, but generally speaking you should always consider using CSS classes.

```
// this normally goes into the `<head>` section of your view
<style type="text/css">
    .long-word {
        color: red
    }
</style>
// ..........................
   <div>
        <p>@word</p> 
        @if(word.Length <4) <!--anything under 4 char will be known as a short word.-->
        {
        <p>@word is a short word</p>
        }
        @elseif(word.StartsWith("x")) <!-- this is your check-->
        {
        <p class="long-word">@word</p> <!-- and this is where you apply your style  -->
        }
  </div>
```